# reputation module installation in phpbb3

Tags: phpbb, phpbb3

Hi i am trying to install phpbb-reputation system i followed the xml file for installation but while executing `install_reputation.php` i am getting this error `ERROR: Could not open the file ./styles/afterburnerafterburner_config.html for reading.`There are many errors in the same fashin. where i gues it is not going inside afterburner/template folder where .html file exists. where should i check this?
More error samples:

```
Refreshing the proFormell template
ERROR: Could not open the file ./styles/proFormellcaptcha_recaptcha.html for reading.
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like it's a permissions issue; if hosting on a LAMP server, just run `chmod 755 * -R` in the website root directory. Alternatively you could also change file permissions using an FTP client

Comment: no i am doing all this in windows system. but ultimately it has to be integrated in LAMP. But right it is on WAMP. Any idea? one more thing i want to ask can disable all other themes? if yes then from where i can?

Comment: Not sure, personally I don't use IIS & PHP together - always proved to be too annoying.  Sorry no idea re: your second question about themes, the documentation should shed light on that.

Comment: Seems like yo uare not the only one having problems. See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26444663/installing-a-reputation-system-on-phpbb-causes-layout-problems/27161565#27161565