# Installing a reputation system on phpbb causes layout problems

Tags: phpbb3

I have tried several times to install a reputation system mod on my phpbb forum. But it always causes the problem that my layout is messed up.

Is there a way I can work around this?

The mod I use is the rep system by pico88. I cant show the layout problems because the forum is up and running.

Maybe there is a reputation system that doesnt do anything with the layout?

Answer (score 0):

That's a bit of a heavy modification for the server. I'm not getting into details. Speaking if which you should have posted some more. Like phpBB version, mod version, style etc. I can only guess what you are referring to without details...

I suggest you to use the Ajax like/dislike system By SiteSplat. Its Premium plugin and ppular among its users base. You can find it [Here](http://www.sitesplat.com/phpBB3/index.php) and the premium themes with support are [Here](http://themeforest.net/user/ThemeSplat/portfolio?ref=ThemeSplat)